# Error granting specific user account access

Tags: excel, vba

Not understanding why the following results with a compile error, please help.

problem experienced within VBA, attempting to create user account access with appropriate access and falling a little short of the mark

```
Sub CheckUser()
Dim UserRow, SheetCol As Long
Dim SheetNm As String
With Sheet1
.Calculate

If .Range("B8").Value = Empty Then 'Incorrect Username
MsgBox "Please enter a correct Username"
Exit Sub
End If

If .Range("B7").Value <> True Then 'Incorrect password
MsgBox "Please enter correct Password"
Exit Sub
End If

LoginForm.Hide
.Range("B5,B6").ClearContents
UserRow = .Range("B8").Value 'User row

For SheetCol = 7 To 19
SheetNm = .Cells(5, SheetCol).Value 'Sheet Name
If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then
Sheets(SheetNm).Unprotect "123"
Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then
Sheets(SheetNm).Protect "123"
Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "x" Then Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Next SheetCol
End With
End Sub

Sub CloseworkBook()
Sheet15 Activate
Dim WkSht As Worksheet
For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If WkSht <> "Start" Then WkShy.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Next WkSht
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Thought i was doing well...guess not

Expect the Macro to function yet it fails

Comment: When you step through the code (F8) where does the error occur. You may also want to consider splitting your code into different modules so that you can more easily see where errors occur (e.g. one module to check username/password, another to set protections).

Comment: You're not declaring `Sheet1`

Comment: Many issues with the code. However  for compile error 
`If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then` have no corresponding `End If`. Also `Sheet15 Activate` may be `Sheet15.Activate` .   And  `WkShy` may be `WkSht`.

Comment: `Option Explicit` always.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the comments, some typos and errors in your code. I've edited all that I could find with a quick look. Also I'd recommend using the [rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) com add-in. It has many powerful features that will help you [improve and spot errors](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) in your code.

```
Option Explicit 'Always add this to all your modules (in VBE--> tools--> Require Variable declaration)

Sub CheckUser()
Dim UserRow, SheetCol As Long
Dim SheetNm As String
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet 'declare worksheet
Set Sheet1 =Sheets("Sheet1") 'set worksheet

With Sheet1
.Calculate

If .Range("B8").Value = Empty Then 'Incorrect Username
MsgBox "Please enter a correct Username"
Exit Sub
End If

If .Range("B7").Value <> True Then 'Incorrect password
MsgBox "Please enter correct Password"
Exit Sub
End If

LoginForm.Hide
.Range("B5,B6").ClearContents
UserRow = .Range("B8").Value 'User row

For SheetCol = 7 To 19
SheetNm = .Cells(5, SheetCol).Value 'Sheet Name
If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then
Sheets(SheetNm).Unprotect "123"
Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then
Sheets(SheetNm).Protect "123"
Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If ' added missing End if statement

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "x" Then Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Next SheetCol
End With
End Sub

Sub CloseworkBook()
Sheet15.Activate 'Sheet 15.Activate Not Sheet15 Activate
Dim WkSht As Worksheet
For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If WkSht <> "Start" Then WkSht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden 'edited WkShy to the correct WkSht
Next WkSht
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so very much everyone, helped me a great deal, truly appreciated :-D